# Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : unable to load shared object | Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: r, rcpp, shared-objects, r-package

I am new to R package development. I am developing a package (bartpkg) that has in its `src/` folder one (prime) cpp file and some helper cpp (`X.Cpp`, `Y.Cpp`) and one c file (`Z.C`) and their header files (`X.h`, `Y.h` and `Z.h`)

I am getting the following error when I do 'Build & Reload' in Rstudio.

```
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) :
  unable to load shared object '/Users/abcd/BART/bart_pkg1/src/bartpkg.so':
  dlopen(/Users/abcd/BART/bart_pkg1/src/bartpkg.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN3RNG4nfixElm
  Referenced from: /Users/abcd/BART/bart_pkg1/src/bartpkg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/abcd/BART/bart_pkg1/src/bartpkg.so
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_all -> load_dll -> library.dynam2 -> dyn.load
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I have followed the basic guidelines to build the package.

The .R file has directive `#' @useDynLib bartpkg` in the right place.

Also, the prime cpp file has the following tags in the right place.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//' @param x A single integer.
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
```

And my `NAMESPACE` file shows `useDynLib(bartpkg)` correctly.

I am able to see the `bartpkg.so` shared object file in the `src/` directory.

I tried in the terminal this command `c++filt -n _ZN3RNG4nfixElm` and was able to see that the symbol in the error

> Symbol not found: __ZN3RNG4nfixElm' is coming from the .C file RNG.C and is because of a function 'nfix'.

But even if I remove the function 'nfix' or remove the `RNG.C` file altogether, the same error:

> Symbol not found: __ZN3RNG4nfixElm

can it  be a flag issue that my compiler is not able to compile the 'C' file?
I am able to see that all the cpp files generate respective object files, but I dont see anything like that for the C file.

I have a `Makevars` in the `src/` directory just having one line

```
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
```

which I basically just copied from another package, more because my understanding with Rcpp and the which flags to work with is really less.

I am using RStudio is the session info is

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] bartpkg_0.1.0        packrat_0.4.8-1      Rcpp_0.12.8          msm_1.6.4            LaplacesDemon_16.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] roxygen2_5.0.1  lattice_0.20-34 mvtnorm_1.0-5   digest_0.6.10   grid_3.3.1      magrittr_1.5  
 [7] stringi_1.1.2   Matrix_1.2-7.1  splines_3.3.1   tools_3.3.1     stringr_1.1.0   survival_2.39-5
[13] parallel_3.3.1  rsconnect_0.5   inline_0.3.14   expm_0.999-0
```

I am stuck at this problem for weeks now. Trying to read the 'Writing the R extension' page and not able to figure this out.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you run `compileAttributes()` if you add/remove/change interface or else your `RcppExport.cpp` will be out of sync and can give such errors.

Comment: You don't need the `PKG_LIBS = ....` anymore. That changes a few years ago.  See what `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` creates for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @DirkEddelbuettel 
_"Make sure you run compileAttributes() if you add/remove/change interface or else your RcppExport.cpp will be out of sync and can give such errors."_

> My understanding is, and I checked it too, that whenever I do Build and Reload in Rstudio, it automatically does the `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` for me, so I needn't do it myself. 

Also, regarding your second reply, I did not create the pacakge with the help of **Rcpp.Package.skeleton**. I created it manually.


> Any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed, RStudio will do that for you so that is not it.  In which case I would then suggest to look carefully and what files are compiled and linked into the shared library -- because you do seem be missing a symbol.   Sometimes it helps to start small, via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or the File -> NewProject -> Package -> PackageWithRcpp option in RStudio.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I just recreated the entire package with File -> NewProject -> Package -> PackageWithRcpp option in RStudio. The same error persists. Really disheartened right now. Do not know what to do.
> Some extra pointers..
1. There are no MakeVars file in the src folder.
2. I am  building my Package with PackRat.
3.  I can see the symbol I am missing, but I do not know why is it happening.
Any help, please?

Comment: <shrug> I never use packrat, I never have the problem.  But seriously: you did _not_ supply a reproducible example so _nobody can know_ what you did wrong.  Start from a working example, and add one new header and source file defining a trivial function, call that.  It if still works build from there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Could it be that I have the .C and the .Cpp files in the src directory and somehow .C is not getting compiled? I think so because the missing symbol is from the .C file and also because I do not know if  Rcpp is compiling the .C file at all..

Comment: Beginner error:  If you call C functions you **must** precede their declarations with `extern "C"`.

Comment: We all wasted hours on this because you did not bother to supply a [minimally reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).